# Use `grub-md5-crypt` in a script where user is prompted for password to encrypt

Tags: scripting, rhel, grub

As you already know from title, I want to configure an encrypted password for grub in `/etc/grub.conf`. I want to use a single script, where I will use `grub-md5-crypt`, enter my password that I want to encrypt, and `sed` that encrypted output in `/etc/grub.conf`. Second part is fine for me. but how to handle password prompt in the script:

```
[root@localhost ssh]# grub-md5-crypt 
Password: 
Retype password: 
$1$3L3j7$lkZs92MnlmQkVYiCH9dtJ.
```

How can I automatically save the encrypted password in a variable or manage it somehow, so that in the next line of my script I can `sed` it like  this:

```
sed -i '/^[# ]*timeout.*/a $hashedpwd/' /etc/grub.conf
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Hashvalue="$(echo -e "P@$$w0rd\nP@$$w0rd" | grub-md5-crypt 2>/dev/null | tail --lines=1)"
```

#### Example

```
$ echo $Hashvalue
$1$F9fFw$czx0UwjdaorHHXf1QHRzi1
```